# Reuse test classes across multiple modules in same project

Tags: java, maven, selenium

```
--project
---------module A
         -src
            -main
            -test
            -POM
            -resourses -a
---------module B
          -src
             -main
             -test
             -POM
             -resources -b
```

as per the above structure, my project has two modules and each has its own test classes.
Module A test classes use "resources -a" & Module B test classes use "resources -b".

my requirement is to use Module A Test Classes & resources in Module B. 
for this, I use `maven-jar-plugin`.

steps I have followed as follows.

1. added maven jar plugin to Module A  POM

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.2</version>

           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>test-jar</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. add maven plugin to Module B POM as well

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.2</version>
       </plugin>
   ```
3. add dependencies to Module B POM

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>liyathabara</groupId>
       <artifactId>module A</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>

   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>liyathabara</groupId>
       <artifactId>module A</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <type>test-jar</type>
   </dependency>
   ```

after following those steps it's possible to use the module A  test classes in module B.

**Issues as follows,**

1. is there a way to use Module A resources inside Module B?  cause methods in Module A need resources in Module A. When executing inside module B it's looking for resources in Module B, but the required resources in module A. need to come up with a way to share resources.
2. any good approach to overcome the requirement without issues.

   *requirement: use test classes in other modules, the same project*

Comment: If you want to use test classes in different modules, it's a sure sign that you have code duplication across modules. Re-use code not test cases.

Comment: @Nicktar my module A is for my API layer. Module B is for my Ui layer.  at this point, I need to write a test which is using both API & UI. to create some data I need to run my API scripts inside my UI. there's No duplication.

Comment: You are writing about `resources` do you mean resources like property files or images or do you mean jar files? (Test classes?)

Comment: @khmarbaise test classes

Comment: To reuse test class the best and cleanest solution is to make a separate module put your test classes into src/main/java and write tests in src/test/java for your classes afterwards you can simply add them as scope:test to the modules where you need them.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks.  I think that's the best thing to do.